# Data transmitted via ADB makes emulator stopping

Tags: adb, android-emulator

Recently, I was running the Visual Studio Android emulator and TCPView, and I saw that the emulator keeps stopping.

- When I click "Wait", then some data is sent via adb to the emulator and the same amount of data comes back via adb on another connection.
- When I click "Stop app", then data is transmitted without stopping.

Then I stopped the VM and reset it where it started from the beginning.